# Cumulative distribution function equals almost surely

Tags: probability, distributions

Let $F_1, F_2$ - two continuous CDF.

if $F_1 = F_2\quad F_2$ almost surely (i.e. probability of $x$ where $F_1(x)\neq F_2(x)$ is zero with respect to probability with CDF $F_2$).

Then $F_1 = F_2$ (everywhere).

Comment: Hint: consider the contrapositive.  If the $F_i$ are continuous and there exists $x$ for which $F_1(x)\ne F_2(x),$ can  you show ${\Pr}_{F_2}(F_1 \ne F_2) \gt 0$?

Comment: Thank you, reformulation of statement helps.

Answer (score 1):

By contrapositive, if exists $x$ such that $F_1(x) \neq F_2(x)$

if $F_2(x) < F_1(x)$, then choose $y>x$ such that $F_2(y) > F_2(x)$ and $F_2(y) < F_1(x)$.
Then $F_2(x) \neq F_1(x)$ on $[x,y]$ (by the monotony of F_1) and ${\Pr}_{F_2}([x,y]) \ge F_2(y) - F_2(x) > 0$.

if $F_2(x) > F_1(x)$, then choose $y<x$ such that $F_2(y) < F_2(x)$ and $F_2(y) > F_1(x)$.
Then $F_2(x) \neq F_1(x)$ on $[y,x]$ (by the monotony of F_1) and ${\Pr}_{F_2}([y,x]) \ge F_2(x) - F_2(y)$ > 0.

Note I use only continuity of $F_2$ and statement true if $F_1$ is arbitrary.

Comment: +1: the final remark is insightful.